# How to install SMS Servers and Phone Servers?

Tags: software-rec, telephony, messaging, sms

If we want our servers to email, we know that we should install `sendmail` or `qmail`. If we want our servers to send SMS or robot calling (e.g voice confirmation [insecure method] ), what should we install on our servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subject says "servers", but your question is about clients.
I'll answer the question in the body. Two alternatives:

1. [Twilio](http://twilio.com)

   Twilio is a platform that provides a wide range of tools to make it easy to integrate voice and SMS with your web app.

   I had good success recently with their [PHP Quickstart guide](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest) (which you can test for free with a trial account) to send SMS to a phone.
2. Directly email SMS gateway

   Also remember that if you're just trying to send a SMS to a small set of phone numbers that you know provider for, you can just [email the provider's SMS gateway directly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways)